# SWI Prolog pass a goal with non-zero arity through the command line arguments

Tags: bash, prolog, swi-prolog, logic-programming

SWI Prolog allows the execution of a goal before top level with non zero arity as follows

```
swipl -s consultingfile.pl -g start
```

however when a predicate with non zero arity is specified as follows

```
swipl -s consultingfile.pl -g start(1)
```

It gives an error

```
syntax error near unexpected token '('
```

What should be done to pass a non-zero arity predicate as a goal before top level?

Comment: What if you place it between quotes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this has nothing/not much to do with SWI-prolog itself, but more with the command line handler.

If I place the goal between single quotes (`''`), it works:

```
swipl -s consultingfile.pl -g 'start(1)'
```

The brackets are probably wrongly interpreted by the shell.

If I use your command it gives:

```
$ swipl -s consultingfile.pl -g start(1)
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

Mind however the `bash` before the colon. That means control is never really given to `swipl`, it is bash that complains about the brackets.

In general it is better to put items into quotes in order to group content as a single parameter.

Comment: Thank you. That helped :)
so dumb that I missed trying that XD